# Полноразмерный фон кнопки tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button, background

Нужно с помощью *tkinter* наложить задний фон кнопки, но так, чтобы он помещался на поле кнопки.

```py
vac_image = PhotoImage(file = 'vacci.png')

button_sites = Button(bg = '#fff', command = openweb_gov, relief = RIDGE, image = vac_image)
button_sites.place(x=77, y=430, height = 50, width = 70)
```

Подскажите, потому что у меня на поле кнопки отображается только фрагмент картинки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


root = Tk()
root.geometry("430x160+200+200")

def openweb_gov():
    pass
    
image = Image.open("lena-2.png")                       # установите свое изображение
resized_bg = image.resize((70, 70), Image.ANTIALIAS)
vac_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_bg)             

button_sites = Button(
    bg = '#fff', 
    command = openweb_gov, 
    relief = RIDGE, 
    image = vac_image
)
button_sites.place(x=10, y=10, height = 50, width = 70)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**lena-2.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]